# Quantum Brain Dynamics (QBD)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, biology, perception

I found an article that broach this matter, I wanted to know if this [Quantum Brain Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_brain_dynamics) (QBD) is treated in the scientific environment with such seriousness or is it some kind of unfounded hypotesis that utilize QFT just to get credibility.

Comment: As physics is pure garbage, but it might have some philosophical value, which I also doubt.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_brain_dynamics ?

Comment: Yeah, but I also did find this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/q-bio/0309009.pdf, which there are some formulas that uses DIrac notation and this kinda stuff, I don't really understand the math to say if it is valid or not

Comment: It is not part of established science if that's what you're asking